# How to write this query using laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to execute this MySQL query using Laravel Eloquent

`SELECT * FROM cashes WHERE idcash = 4 AND (institution = 1 or branch = 1) LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Use the callback with `where`.

Comment: First, you should try it on your own. If you find any error then post it here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects

Comment: Create model for this table and then try [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

Comment: Here is the code  `self::query()->where('idash', $id)->where(['institution' => $emp->institution, 'branch' => $emp->branch], '', '', 'and')->first()` and it gives me `select * from cashes where idash = 4 and (institution = 1 and branch = 1) limit 1`

Comment: Please my main problem is at the level of the `WHERE clause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$cashes = Cash::where('idcash ', 4)
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('institution', 1)->orWhere('branch', 1);
    })
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
```

For see sql query use `->toSql()` instead of `->get()`, or use `->dd()` instead of `->get()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Cash` model:

```php
$cashes = Cash::where([
        ['institution', 1],
        ['id_cash', 4]
    ])
    ->orWhere([
        ['branch', 1],
        ['id_cash', 4]
    ])->limit(1)->get();
```

Hope it helps.